# Clear dropped items every 5 minutes

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am coding a Spigot 1.8.9 plugin and am trying to clear drops every 5 minutes but before the items are cleared I want to give a 60, 30, 15, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1 second warning then have them cleared.

I tried using the following but it doesn't have the countdown warning.

```
public static void startDropTimer() {
    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(MyPlugin.getPlugin(), new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            clearAllDrops();
        }
    }, 6000, 6000);
}
```

How can I implement the warning countdown before clearing the drops?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @JacobG. I edited to make my question more clear.

Comment: Don't do it! Players **hate** this. The game **already** clears items that are older then 5 minutes! having a scheduled repeating task that does it intermittently RUINS Redstone contraptions, ruins players looking for their death drops, and gets done for LITERALLY 0 REASON. Many players will outright refuse to play on a server that clears drops on a schedule.

You are 1000x better off not doing it, or having some other form of way of tracking high entity counts, hopefully per chunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `timer` variable to store passed time

```
long remainingTimeInSeconds = 300; //5 minutes
```

Then update your task to reduce this timer every **20 ticks**(20 ticks = 1 second in Bukkit). With the update task, make checks on your timer variable to verify if a message should be sent or if the drops should be cleared:

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(MyPlugin.getPlugin(), new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        currentTimeInSeconds--;

        switch(remainingTimeInSeconds) {
           case 60:
           case 30:
           case 15:
           case 10:
           case 5:
           case 3:
           case 2:
           case 1:
           //Send message remainingTimeInSeconds seconds left until drops are cleared!
           break;

           case 0:
           clearAllDrops();
           remainingTimeInSeconds = 300; //Reset your timer
           break;             
        }    

    }
}, 20L, 0);
```